# Applied linear algebra (eigenvalue and eigenvectors)

Tags: linear-algebra

In a population of 50,000 there are 20,000 nonsmokers, 20,000 smokers of one pack or less a day, and 10,000 smokers of more than one pack a day. During any month it is likely that only 10 percent of the nonsmokers will become smokers of one pack or less a day and the rest will remain nonsmokers, 20 percent of the smokers of a pack or less will quit smoking, 30 percent will increase their smoking to more than one pack a day, 30 percent of the heavy smokers will remain smokers but decrease their smoking to one pack or less, and 10 percent will go cold turkey and quit. After one month what part of the population is in each category? After two months how many are in each category? After one year how many are in each category?

Comment: I believe you are missing part of the problem statement. When you do  complete it please make sure to also include your thoughts on the question and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Now completed sir

Answer (score 0):

You can build a matrix that represents the state transitions and then compute the correct powers of it times your state vector.

Let us say $v = \begin{bmatrix} x\\y\\z \end {bmatrix} $ is your state vector where $x, y$ and $z $ are, respectively, the percentage of non-smokers, light smokers and heavy smokers.

Then the passing of one month can be found by calculating $T(v) $, where $T $ is a linear transformation that computes the state changes. Thus all we need to check is how the percentages of non-smokers, light smokers and heavy smokers change in a month and put that in $T $'s columns.

If $v = \begin {bmatrix} 1\\0\\0\end {bmatrix}$ then $T(v) = \begin {bmatrix} 0.9\\0.1\\0\end {bmatrix}$, which represents the state change of non-smokers.

For light smokers:

$T(\begin {bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end {bmatrix}) = \begin {bmatrix}0.2\\0.5\\0.3\end {bmatrix} $

And for heavy smokers:

$T(\begin {bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end {bmatrix}) = \begin {bmatrix}0.1\\0.3\\0.6\end {bmatrix} $

And the matrix representation of $T $ is

$$T = \begin {bmatrix} 0.9&0.2&0.1\\0.1&0.5&0.3\\0&0.3&0.6\end {bmatrix} $$

All you have to do is build your initial $v $ and then compute $Tv, T^2v$ and $T^{12}v $.